# dot net core project, using jquery maxlength and count plugins inside site.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, jquery-plugins

I am wondering if I am even doing this right. I download a jquery plugin and place it in the lib folder. I then write the path name for the plug-in inside _layout.cshtml just like the other scripts. I then go into site.js to write some client side code hoping to use my new plugin and it says "$(.....)maxlength is not a function". So Im thinking my site.js file does not have access to my plugins. What am I missing here? Am I supposed to add the plugins in somewhere else as well so site.js can use them, does not make sense to me.

inside _layout.cshtml:

```
  <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/lib/jQuery.Maxlength-master/jquery.maxlength.min.js"> 
    </script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
  <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

  @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

inside site.js just some code trying to use new plugin:

```
$("input").maxlength();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this jquery `jquery.min.js` is duplicated with `jquery-1.5.js`. So, you can delete this script.

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And their order should be changed.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jQuery.Maxlength-master/jquery.maxlength.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

In Index.cshtml, add a text box.

```
<input type="text" onchange="change()" maxlength="30"/>
```

In site.js.

```
function change() {
 console.log($("input").maxlength())
}
```

Result
[image]